Objective-c conforming protocols property attributes conflict
Can I make a class conforms to two protocols with same property but different access level attribute?
E.g.
@interface Test () <ProtocolA, ProtocolB> {
}
@end

@protocol ProtocolA <NSObject>
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) id prop;
@end

@protocol ProtocolB <NSObject>
@property(nonatomic, readonly) id prop;

What I'm trying to achieve is to expose prop only in test environment. In test cases, I'll set prop to be a mocked object.
Thanks!
I tried to expose prop in ProtocolB to be readwrite and set it successfully in tests, however, this is less ideal since I sacrifice the access level.
